# Table rows collapse in HTML, but not from JQuery script

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make table rows collapse if they contain no data. The rows get changed from within a JQuery script. I know they collapse if I place the table inside my HTML. I can create many rows and use `display:block` or `display:none` and the rows collapse/display as expected. Here is the markup:

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="display:block;">
        <td id="someid">Test</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is example code I'm using to change the `<tr>`:

```
var newtr = "<tr style='display:none;'><td id='someid'></td><td></td></tr>"
$("td#someid").parent().replaceWith(newtr);
```

The contents of the rows change, but they don't collapse. I'm using Firebug to see that `display:none` is being inserted. Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just add `hide()`:

```
$("td#someid").parent().replaceWith(newtr).hide();
```

**[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/KmxRB/)**

Comment: Why? Because I didn't know I could do that, and so easily. :) I like this. I don't know JQuery/Javascript very much. Thank you!

Comment: @rwkiii Have a read of [jQuery tutorials here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) and [JavaScript tutorials here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the `tr`; *if you want to clear the fields and hide the row*, I would recommend simply hiding the row and then clearing the cells afterwards, something like this should do the trick:

```
// this will explicitly set the CSS display property to none and clear the children
$('td#someid').parent().css('display', 'none').children('td').each(function()
{
    $(this).text('');
});

// or you could hide the parent and then clear the children
$('td#someid').parent().hide().children('td').each(function()
{
    $(this).text('');
});
```

Comment: Using `.hide` definitely adds some capability for me. I'm not understanding why I would hide the row and also set CSS to `display:none`. Both of you gave me good answers. The replacement rows are generated in an XSLT stylesheet where I create a JSON object. Your answers having me thinking about simplifying some of my code in the stylesheet. Thank you Richard.

Comment: You wouldn't need to use both examples, just either/or. I would definitely recommend simplifying things were possible with good use of CSS.